# Laptop shuts down after I choose Ubuntu in grub menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, shutdown, msi

I want to install Ubuntu on my [MSI GP62 7RD Leopard](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/GP62-7RD-Leopard/Specification) laptop. After going through a lot of trouble and solutions, I was finally able to install it.

However, when I choose Ubuntu from the [grub](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) menu, it shows the UBUNTU logo then  shuts down.

How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Which version / release number of Ubuntu? Does this happen when you boot and run from a LiveUSB? Please click [edit] and enhance your question by providing this info. Please don't use Add Comment as you lose all formatting when you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check secure boot isn't causing issues, It could be GPT disk type that's causing the failure to boot second image

Comment: Please also disable Fast Boot as well as Secure Boot in the BIOS/firmware settings.